# Turn field names into column names for specific variables and fill them with certain logic

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below:

```
product<-c("ab","ab","ab","ac","ac","ac")
shop<-c("sad","sad","sad","sadas","fghj","xzzv")
category<-c("a","a","a","c","b","b")
tempr<-c(35,35,14,24,14,5)
value<-c(0,0,-6,8,4,0)
store<-data.frame(product,shop,category,tempr,value)


product  shop category tempr value
1      ab   sad        a    35     0
2      ab   sad        a    35     0
3      ab   sad        a    14    -6
4      ac sadas        c    24     8
5      ac  fghj        b    14     4
6      ac  xzzv        b     5     0
```

I want to transform this dataframe in a way that I will keep the unique product names and turn shop names from field values to column names (and the opposite). I want to fill this data frame with a combination of `tempr` and its relative `value` but only for the value that is not 0 otherwise the cells should be empty. However, as you noticed I have records that have the same `product` and `shop`, but different tempr and value numbers (ab-sad). The problem is that they overwrite each other. In that case (same name,same shop but different `tmpr`-`value`) the non-zero case should prevail. For example 170(62) should be dispalyed instead of 170(0) if they both exist.The cells should also be empty in case that a product does not exist in a shop. An example of the final form is:

```
store2
  product    sad sadas  fghj xzzv
1      ab 14(-6)                 
2      ac        24(8) 14(4)
```

**1st possible approach:**

```
store2 <- matrix(NA,ncol=length(unique(store$shop)),nrow=length(unique(store$product)))
colnames(store2) <- unique(store$shop)
rownames(store2) <- unique(store$product)

for(i in 1:ncol(store)) {
  store2[store[i,'product'],store[i,'shop']] <- paste0(store[i,c('tempr')],'(',store[i,'value'],')')
}
```

**2nd possible approach:**

```
library(tidyverse)
store %>%
    mutate(shop = factor(shop, levels = unique(shop))) %>%
    filter(value != 0) %>%
    mutate(val = sprintf("%s(%s)", tempr, value)) %>%
    select(product, shop, val) %>%
    group_by(product) %>%
    complete(shop) %>%
    spread(shop, val)
```

Except from this result I want to be able to use `category` as well with the same logic. The picture below shows all the possible combinations that I wish with the same filling logic.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand the question, but the code below produces your example dataframe.

```
library(tidyverse)
product<-c("ab","ab","ab","ac","ac","ac")
shop<-c("sad","sad","sad","sadas","fghj","xzzv")
category<-c("a","a","a","c","b","b")
tempr<-c(35,35,14,24,14,5)
value<-c(0,0,-6,8,4,0)
store<-data.frame(product,shop,category,tempr,value)


store %>% filter(value != 0 ) %>%  # Remove 0 values 
  mutate(combined =  paste0(tempr,"(",value,")")) %>% # Combine columns for spread
  select(-tempr,-value) %>%  #
  spread(shop,combined) # spread to create shop columns and temr/value values. 

  #       product category  fghj    sad     sadas
  # 1      ab        a      <NA>    14(-6)  <NA>
  # 2      ac        b       14(4) <NA>     <NA>
  # 3      ac        c      <NA>   <NA>     24(8)
```

Comment: Nice - maybe just missing the empty column xzzv?

Answer (score 1):

```
store$shop<-factor(store$shop,levels=c("sad","sadas","fghj","xzzv")) 
 #to avoid the change of column sequence of final outcome

store$tv<-ifelse(store$value==0,"",paste(store$tempr,"(",store$value,")",sep=""))

cast(store[,c(-3,-4,-5)],product~shop,function(x) paste(x,sep="",collapse=""), value="tv")
#due to one colname of the original store dataset is "value", firstly masked 
#the original "value" column,otherwise, it automatically used as value-fill 
# column
```

```
product    sad sadas  fghj xzzv
     ab 14(-6)                 
     ac        24(8) 14(4)"
```